# You may need a dictionary

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, sequence, word-sequence

Can you find the missing words (number of question marks equal number of letters)

> puzzling - puzzled - perplexed - ??????? - ???????? - ??????? - ????????? - ?????????? - ?????????? - ???????

using these examples?

> cynicism - inclination - urge - earnestly - sincere - pretense

> froth - agitation - briskly - impatient - provoked - stimulate

Hint 1:

> if you dont have google, this is impossible

Comment: Great puzzle, did you use Apple Dictionary?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Ask Google to define each word, and click the first linked word that shows up in the definition. For example, [define inclination](https://www.google.com/search?q=define+inclination) has definition:
> "1. a person's natural tendency or [urge](https://www.google.com/search?q=define+urge) to act or feel in a particular way; a disposition or propensity."
> So, inclination goes to urge.

The missing words are hence:

> [puzzling](https://www.google.com/search?q=define+puzzling) - [puzzled](https://www.google.com/search?q=define+puzzled) - [perplexed](https://www.google.com/search?q=define+perplxed) - [baffled](https://www.google.com/search?q=define+baffled) - [restrain](https://www.google.com/search?q=define+restrain) - [oneself](https://www.google.com/search?q=define+oneself) - [emphasize](https://www.google.com/search?q=define+emphasize) - [prominence](https://www.google.com/search?q=define+prominence) - [projecting](https://www.google.com/search?q=define+projecting) - [outward](https://www.google.com/search?q=define+outward)

The sequence stops here, because

> [outward](https://www.google.com/search?q=define+outward) has no linked words in its definitions.

Comment: I see it depends on the Google Language settings. For example, my default language is English + Native. So, it doesnt work for me. It gives a different definition. If I set it to only English, it works.